# Why static method overrides base class non-static method?

Tags: c++, overriding, static-methods, language-lawyer

```
struct B {
  void foo () {}
};

struct D : B {
  using B::foo;
  static void foo () {}
};

int main ()
{
  D obj;
  obj.foo();  // calls D::foo() !?
}
```

Member method and `static` member method are entirely different for 2 reasons:

1. `static` method doesn't override the
   virtual functions in base `class`
2. Function pointer signature for both
   the cases are different

When a method is called by an object, shouldn't the member method have higher preference logically ? (Just that C++ allows `static` method to be called using object, [would it be considered as an overridden](http://www.ideone.com/LgcZ1) method ?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The rule that you are seeing is described in ISO/IEC 14882:2003 7.3.3 [namespace.udecl] / 12 :

> When a *using-declaration* brings names from a base class into a derived class scope, member functions in the derived class override and/or hide member functions with the same name and parameter types in a base class (rather than conflicting).

Without this rule, the function call would be ambiguous.

Comment: Is it applicable for `static` members also ? If yes then why does `static` methods conflict with `virtual` methods ?

Comment: @iammilind Because this only applies to the using declaration.

Comment: @iammilind: `virtual` and `static` don't make any difference at this point because it is just overload resolution that determining which function should be called on your `D` object.

Comment: That's the least obvious thing here: there's no reason static methods need to be considered at all when doing non-static resolution, but that's just the way things work.

Comment: @Eamon: it's all a matter of "fragile" base class. The problem stems from the fact that the static method may be invoked from with a `dot`. From this point on, **hiding** is mandatory, otherwise *introducing* `foo` in the base class would potentially break **all** client code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you can't overload a static method using a non-static method with the same signature.

Now, if you try:

```
struct D {
  void foo () {}
  static void foo () {}
};
```

It will trigger an error.

I'm not really sure why in case of `using B::foo` it is actually silently ignored without triggering an error/warning (at least on GCC 4.5.1).